# Confusion about Spring namespaces and how tags such as <security:http> and <p:someProp> require/ don't require prefixes

Tags: xml, spring

So far in my very short Spring development experience, I've been copying the xml namespace declarations and a lot of the spring configuration from online or from Spring recipe books as they relate to my use-cases. I don't understand how tags in spring xml files take on the ability to have or not have prefixes in the tags. For example, I've seen online examples of Spring configuration files like below:

```
<security:http/>
or
<http>

<si:channel/>
or
<channel>


<si:gateway/>
or
<gateway>
```

Could someone demystify this please? Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: The problem is not related to Spring, is related to XML, when You define a namespace with `xmlns="springXSD.xsd"` You don't need a prefix, but when You use `xmlns:hello="springXSD.xsd"`, You need to put the prefix before every element of the schema. You can read more here http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp Cheers

Answer (score 1):

This question is not related to spring, it's related to XML.

When you define the main tag in your `spring configuration`, You use tags like:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:sws="http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services"
    xsi:schemaLocation="...">
```

This will mean that you will use 4 schemas, `beans`, `xsi`, `context`, `aop`, and `sws`. The first schema (defined as `xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"`), will be the **default schema**, this mean, that you dont need to specify a prefix when you use some of the elements defined in the `xsd file`, when you need to use a tag of the `xmlns:xsi=http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop` schema, You need to prefix `xsi` for every element defined in the schema.

You always need to close the xml tag with a exactly same xml tag `(<si:foo>...</si:foo>)`.

In your example, if you change you definition of `xmlns` from `<beans ... xmlns:security='path'>` to `<beans ... xmlns:foo>` the tags that start with `security` will be invalidated, and You need to replace all tags to `<foo:bar>`